# Clear list in python

Tags: python, list

I have a list a which has some items and another list b to which I append list a. Next I want to clear list a, and repeat the process. But the problem is when I clear list a, my list b also gets clear.

```
for i in range(0,c)
    for j in range(0, c):
        if(x == 1):
            a.append(j)
    b.append(adj_row)
    del adj_row[:]
```

How do I prevent list b from getting erased when list a is cleared?

Comment: You should create a new list everytime.

Comment: @Plutonium smuggler Where is x ? Can you please show some more code .

Comment: Found the solution using the above link. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

A = [1,2,3,4]
B = []

Copying a list in python 
B = A[:]
Otherwise assigning list works like a pointers 
I mean 
B = A
Deleting A values same as deleting B values 
If you do B = A[:] it will not happen